# Free-ing an array of structs obtained through malloc

Tags: c, malloc, free

So I have this struct:

```
typedef struct type {
      int a;
      char* b;
} type;
```

In the `main` program, I make 2 arrays of these structs, and use `malloc()`:

```
type *v;
type *w;
v=malloc(50*sizeof(type));
w=malloc(50*sizeof(type));
```

Now I if I want to free these arrays of structs is it correct to do:

```
free(v);
free(w);
```

?

Comment: If `b` points at something which was allocated dynamically you must be prepared to free that as well.

Comment: Yes, as far as you didn't mallocate something for `b` member. In case you mallocated b members, you must free them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be correct provided that you did not allocate memory for data member

```
char* b;
```

of elements of the arrays.

Otherwise you need at first to free the memory pointed to by this data member and only then to free the original pointers.

For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) free( v[i].b );
free( v );
```

Take into account that if this data member was initialized by the address of a string literal then you shall not free this memory because string literals have the static storage duration.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is correct.  You only need to pass the pointer returned by `malloc()` and family.

You don't need to mention / supply the size of the allocated memory while calling `free()`. The size will be taken care automatically (by OS).

FWIW, in case, you have allocated dynamic memory to the members, like `w[i].b`s, you need to `free()` them first, because, once you call `free()` on `w`, all the memory allocated in `w[i].b` will become unreachable, hence your program will be leaking memory.

Comment: Yes, I have allocated memory to char*.

Comment: @odin19 Then, you need to free them first, because, once you call free on `w`, all the memory allcated in `w[i].b` will become unreachable, hence will be leaking.